# How to query multiple collections in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have two schema "Users" and "Books".

> Users: _id, isActive type: boolean
>
> Books: userid ref Users, name

I want to query Books which user's isActive is true.

I have one approach that is first query Users with isActive=true and return userid list, then query Books with userid in userid list.

Can anybody has the other better approach to query this situation? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on problem and size of your collections! Your approach is good when you have limited active user. But if you have lot's of active users while your Book collection is small then I would suggest to load the books, and then check if each user is active or not!

Also if you've have lots of active users and lot's of books then storing User's active status inside Book wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: that's too bad, if there are large users and it will take a long time to get userid list.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.2 introduced [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup), which works like left outer join in [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) pipeline.

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {isActive: true}
    },
    {
        $lookup: //left outer join
        {
            from: "books",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "userid",
            as: "books"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$books" // convert each element of "books" array into its own document
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$books" } // remove "books" key. Bring its content out in the root
    }

]).exec(function(err, books) {
    // books with users isActive true
})
```

Note that, we used `User` to aggregate because we want to query `isActive: true`, but after processing the documents in the aggregation pipeline we get `books` at the end.